# Flutter firebase authentication is not working. I've migrated mine to android x too but still gives me error

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get the firebase - auth signing in feature. I got the email,password from the user and i've initialized the auth.instance  but i am not able to register the user due to some errors that i don't even understand.
i installed all the dependencies too.

```
final  auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
String  email;
String password;

onPressed: ()  async{
                try{ final user  = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email,password: password);
                }
                catch(e){
                  print(e);
                }
```

> PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method
>
> 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference, null)

Comment: try `flutter clean` , delete the app in your phone and `flutter run` again

Comment: are you sure you get the values of the email and password before click ?
test this  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: 'test@test.com',password: '13245678');  is it work or not

Comment: i tried flutter clean and reinstalled the app on my phone and it worked.  I am able to see the registered users in firestore but after authentication the app justs quits.

Comment: It's not navigating to a new page -  onPressed: () async {
                   try{ final newuser =  await 
      _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email,password: password);
                     if(newuser!=null){ 
                       Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
                     }
                   }
                   catch(e){
                     print(e);
                   }